# Electron и C++ / C# | Обмен данными напрямую

Tags: c#, c++, node.js, electron

Вопрос заключается только в теории.

Каким способом можно связать **Electron** приложение и некую программу на **C++** или **C#**, суть заключается в мгновенном обмене данными. В идеале конечно же слушать event на **Electron** для асинхронных операций по обработке данных.

Какие есть варианты?

Может есть какой-то способ написать модуль для работы приложения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Electron` использует `nodejs`, поэтому код cpp можно запаковать как `node module`, а затем использовать его в качестве зависимости в своем приложении (см. пример: [Hello World](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html)).

Следующий код эквивалентен этому на JavaScript:

```
module.exports.hello = () => 'world';
```

**hello.cc** (C++):

```
#include <node.h>

namespace demo {

using v8::FunctionCallbackInfo;
using v8::Isolate;
using v8::Local;
using v8::Object;
using v8::String;
using v8::Value;

void Method(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) {
  Isolate* isolate = args.GetIsolate();
  args.GetReturnValue().Set(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "world"));
}

void init(Local<Object> exports) {
  NODE_SET_METHOD(exports, "hello", Method);
}

NODE_MODULE(addon, init)

}  // namespace demo
```

---

См. оригинал на EnSO: [Is it possible to use c++ as back-end for Electron.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43386536/8280225)